# Short footnotes on same line or centered in plain TeX

Tags: xetex, plain-tex

Is there in plain TeX a way to print two short footnotes on the same line (spaced as if in columns) or a single footnote centered?

Comment: Automatically, or only when specified?  Are you really running plain TeX?  The closest I could find was \usepackage{plain}.  And, as usual, a minimal working example (MWE) would help save time for anyone willing to give it a try.

Comment: For the multiple-column footnotes, the TeXbook has a proposed solution in its appendix D: *dirty tricks* pp. 395–398. I couldn't figure out how to put those into the macros, though.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I normally use XeLaTeX, and I did at one point sort of manage to make it work with footmisc + some dirty macros. I assume that if it can be done in plain, it can also be done in more or less the same way in XeLaTeX?

Comment: The first step is solving a problem like this is to look at the source code, and LaTeX and plain TeX are totally different.

Comment: if you normally use xelatex, you need a latex solution not a plain tex one you could clarify which you need (or do you want to just close the question as unclear after all this time?)